# Shared Host - Git and Capistrano

Tags: git, capistrano, shared-hosting

Let's get this clear.
I'm ready to move to another shared host if I must to.
Please, I need as much detail as possible.

In order to have a git repository on my shared host as well as the possibility for deploying my Zend Applications using Capistrano, what, in detail, should I ask to shared host companies ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH-access and git should cover it, I guess. In addition to what dependencies your app is using of course.

**Edit:**

That is, you must be able to log in to your server using ssh, and you should be able to run commands on the server when logged in through ssh. Git should be installed on the server, as Capistrano uses this to check out your code to the path you deploy your app to. Your git repo may be on a different server (like github) if you wish.

If you can't run git on your server, see [deploying with capistrano with remote git repo but without git running on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456275/deploying-with-capistrano-with-remote-git-repo-but-without-git-running-on-product) for a way to get around this limitation.

Comment: Should that SSH-access and git COMMAND or (Git what?) need to have some sort of privileges? Like read/write to any specific directories or something? I will need key/pass pars for Capistrano deployment so I believe, should that be some other requirement? I understand you may not be a shared host company tech guy, but anything that you may add, could help, because I'm clueless about a web shared host company that supports this. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: You need to be able to log in to the server using ssh. The server must have git installed. You must be able to run commands (git in particular) while logged in to the server. You must be able to write to the parts of the file system where your app will reside when logged in through ssh. Capistrano uses ssh to run commands (including git) on your server.

Comment: @harald, plese correct me if I'm wrong. I can also have my repository on github, and use capistrano to deploy the commited files to my shared host, by only using ssh and sftp on the process isn't this precise? Thanks again.

Comment: MEM: I think you need to have git installed on the shared host, as Capistrano will run git (on the server) to check out the code to be deployed. Maybe it's possible to work around this, but that's how it works by default. The repo can be on github or elsewhere, no problem.

Comment: @all hmm... can anyone please confirm harald suspicions ? It's really important because it will be based on that That I will either stay of leave from this shared host company (because they cannot have git command there).

Comment: Mem, have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456275/deploying-with-capistrano-with-remote-git-repo-but-without-git-running-on-product

Comment: harard, no I haven't and It sure helps me out. Thanks a lot! :) Please edit your answers with your last comment suggestion since it will be easier for me and others understand the where is the answer. Is that ok for you? Regards and thanks again.